# Remove code repeated

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a class with two methods which are pretty similar:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass ()
    {

    }

    public IQueryable<tbl_Person> PersonSelect1()
    {
        var ctx = new MyContextSQL();
        var temp = ctx.tbl_Person.Include("tbl_Student").Include("Department").Where(x =>
            (x.int_statID == 2 || x.int_statID == 1 || x.int_statID == 9)
            && (x.department != 90 && x.department != 94) // only difference
            && (x.workID == 789 || x.workID == 567)
            && (x.clientID != 789247)
            && (x.auditID != 9)
            && (x.expDate >= new DateTime(2017, 1, 1))
            && (x.expDate <= DateTime.Today));
        var result = temp.OrderByDescending(x => x.expDate);
        return result;
    }

    public IQueryable<tbl_Person> PersonSelect2()
    {
        var ctx = new MyContextSQL();
        var temp = ctx.tbl_Person.Include("tbl_Student").Include("Department").Where(x =>
            (x.int_statID == 2 || x.int_statID == 1 || x.int_statID == 9)
            && (x.department == 90 || x.department == 94) //only difference
            && (x.workID == 789)
            && (x.clientID != 789247)
            && (x.auditID != 9)
            && (x.expDate >= new DateTime(2017, 1, 1))
            && (x.expDate <= DateTime.Today));
        var result = temp.OrderByDescending(x => x.expDate);
        return result;
    }
}
```

There is only one line different between `PersonSelect1()` and `PersonSelect2()` I don't like how it looks like because there is a lot of code duplicated.
I've been thinking in solve it like this:

```
  public IQueryable<tbl_Person> ThirdMethod()
    {
        var ctx = new MyContextSQL();
        var temp = ctx.tbl_Person.Include("tbl_Student").Include("Department").Where(x =>
            (x.int_statID == 2 || x.int_statID == 1 || x.int_statID == 9)        
            && (x.workID == 789)
            && (x.clientID != 789247)
            && (x.auditID != 9)
            && (x.expDate >= new DateTime(2017, 1, 1))
            && (x.expDate <= DateTime.Today));
        var result = temp.OrderByDescending(x => x.expDate);
        return result;
    }

    public IQueryable<tbl_Person> PersonSelect1()
    {
        var result = this.ThirdMethod().Where(x => (x.department != 90 || x.department != 94));     
        return result;
    }

    public IQueryable<tbl_Person> PersonSelect2()
    {
        var result = this.ThirdMethod().Where(x => (x.department == 90 || x.department == 94));
        return result;
    }
```

Is that the best approach considering that `ThirdMethod()` will connect to the database and then from `PersonSelect1()` or `PersonSelect2()` I will loop again against that collection resulted from `ThirdMethod()` call? I'm considering performance and trying to avoid duplicated code at the same time.

Comment: && (x.department != 90 || x.department != 94) // only difference this Will allways be true

Comment: I pasted an old version of the code and didn't realize about it , it's updated anyways in here now, thanks

Comment: Why don't you create a SQL view with the shared parameters, that way your c# code only calls the view and filters with the `x.department != 90 || x.department != 94` / `x.department != 90 || x.department == 94`

Comment: @maccettura That's a great idea and I like more your idea than the approach I mention in my question

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer in case it works out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable names below are terrible and the syntax might be off, (i have been away from .net for a few of years) but surely the easiest thing to do is have `ThirdMethod` except some parameter and build the query accordingly:

```
public IQueryable<tbl_Person> ThirdMethod(bool isFirstPerson)
{
    var ctx = new MyContextSQL();
    var temp = ctx.tbl_Person.Include("tbl_Student").Include("Department").Where(x =>
        (x.int_statID == 2 || x.int_statID == 1 || x.int_statID == 9) 
        && isfirstPerson ? 
             (x.department != 90 && x.department != 94) : (x.department == 90 || x.department == 94)    
        && (x.workID == 789)
        && (x.clientID != 789247)
        && (x.auditID != 9)
        && (x.expDate >= new DateTime(2017, 1, 1))
        && (x.expDate <= DateTime.Today));
    var result = temp.OrderByDescending(x => x.expDate);
    return result;
}

public IQueryable<tbl_Person> PersonSelect1()
{
    return this.ThirdMethod(true);
}

public IQueryable<tbl_Person> PersonSelect2()
{
    return this.ThirdMethod(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to make the application share the logic, you could create a SQL view that shares the logic and have your C# only do the filter that is different.

This will also increase performance since a view will execute quicker than LINQ2SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but can you do something like this?

```
public IQueryable<tbl_Person> PersonSelect()
{
    var ctx = new MyContextSQL();
    var temp = ctx.tbl_Person.Include("tbl_Student").Include("Department").Where(x =>
        (x.int_statID == 2 || x.int_statID == 1 || x.int_statID == 9)
        && (x.workID == 789 || x.workID == 567)
        && (x.clientID != 789247)
        && (x.auditID != 9)
        && (x.expDate >= new DateTime(2017, 1, 1))
        && (x.expDate <= DateTime.Today));
    var result = temp.OrderByDescending(x => x.expDate);
    return result;
}

public IQueryable<tbl_Person> PersonSelect1()
{
    var ctx = PersonSelect();
    ctx.tbl_Person.Include("tbl_Student").Include("Department").Where(x => (
         (x.department != 90 && x.department != 94);
    return result;
}

public IQueryable<tbl_Person> PersonSelect2()
{
    var ctx = PersonSelect();
    ctx.tbl_Person.Include("tbl_Student").Include("Department").Where(x => (
         (x.department == 90 && x.department == 94);
    return result;
}
```